# Sorting in javascript object based on key and in descending order

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have my JavaScript data as key value and keys are year wise, so I want to sort based on key in descending order

initial records

```
const data = {
    2023: [/* items */],
    2024: [/* items */],
    2022: [/* items */],
    // ... other years
  };
```

expected output

```
const data = {
    2024: [/* items */],
    2023: [/* items */],
    2022: [/* items */],
    // ... other years
  };
```

Comment: You should not rely on the order of the keys in an object. Normally you have some limited control over the order of them (or rather, their enumeration), however, that's easily disturbed. For your specific case *it's literally impossible* to "sort" the keys as you want them. If you need to keep a specific order, use a data structure that is more suitable for it. Most likely, you want an array. It's also possible to use a Map.

Answer (score -1):

Sorting the keys inside an object is unreliable. Don't do that. Instead, you can get the keys of the object, sort them and then you can loop the sorted keys of the object.

```js
const data = {
    2023: [/* items */],
    2024: [/* items */],
    2022: [/* items */],
    // ... other years
  };
  
let keys = Object.keys(data).sort();

console.log(keys);

for (let key in data) {
    console.log(key + " " + JSON.stringify(data[key]));
}
```